# Confusion with how asynchrony happens in this code

Tags: javascript

I new to JS and was learning callbacks and how asynchrony happens with the callbacks. I came across code on https://javascript.info/callbacks which is

```
function loadScript(src) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  document.head.append(script);
}

loadScript('/my/script.js');
// the code below loadScript doesn't wait for the script loading to finish
// ...
```

So, it is said that loadScript function is executed asynchronously but WHY? as far as I know asynchony happens with functions like setTimeOut or xhr object which are executed via event loop. So, why if we only create element in loadScript function, it is executed asynchronously

Comment: Nothing that happens inside what you wrote is asynchronous. However, the contents of the file /my/script.js will not be loaded immediately after `loadScript('/my/script.js');` -- that's the part that's asynchronous. Your code will put the reference to the script in the head, but then the browser will have to actually download the script, and meanwhile the rest of your javascript will be running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording in the article is poorly written.

> The function is called “asynchronously,” because the action (script
>   loading) finishes not now, but later.

The function call is synchronous. The loading of `/my/script.js` is asynchronous, because JS does not wait for the file to be loaded before continuing with its call stack. Any `script` elements created using `createElement` are loaded asyncrhonously - you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> Dynamically inserted scripts (using `document.createElement()`) load
>   asynchronously by default

The following is a better example of asynchronous calling:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = '/my/script.js';
document.head.append(script);

script.onload = function()
{
  // Any code defined inside here is now truly asynchronous.
  // It will not be called until /my/script.js has been loaded.
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kind answer. So, I would like to ask some questions, firstly, only this code: let script = document.createElement('script'); is asynchronous inside loadScript function Right? how about script.src = '/my/script.js';
document.head.append(script); Are they asynchronous as well? Can I imagine it like this, first JS engine sees let script = document.createElement('script') and then pass it into queue then continues running then sees script.src and document.head.append. Then JS engine waits until script is created and then assign src to it. Hope I am clear

Comment: No, the only part of the original function that is 'asynchronous' is the loading of the JS file itself. None of the JS code is executed asynchronously.

Comment: perhaps you mean script.onload = function()
{
  // Any code defined inside here is now truly asynchronous.
  // It will not be called until /my/script.js has been loaded.
} Right? Then I thought asynchronous means when the code is run via event loop so that the rest of the code do not have to wait Right? Or asynchronous means when a function is not run unless other code is finished running

Comment: Yes, in the updated example, anything inside of the `onload` is asynchronous. Asyncronicity in JS is a confusing topic. Here's a great article that explains the topic: https://itnext.io/asynchronicity-in-javascript-93abb3a3f81b

Answer (score 1):

Why should it wait? You are adding an element to DOM, which performs a HTTP request. If we should wait every request performed by DOM elements then out page would be incredibly slow (Yes, I'm simplifying).

By the way, you have to wait that the `onload` event is fired on the element, then you can be sure that the script has been loaded:

```
function loadScript(src, cb) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.onload = cb;
  script.onerror = cb;
  document.head.append(script);
}

loadScript('/my/script.js', function (response) {
   // Your asynchronous code here
});
```

In this example I used callback, since it's the easier to understand. But you can easily convert it to `Promise`s or `async / await`:

```
function loadScript(src) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  document.head.append(script);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => { // ES6 only
    script.onload = res;
    script.onerror = rej;
  });
}

loadScript('/my/script.js')
.then(() => {
   // Your asynchronous code here
})
.catch(() => {
  // Error handling
});
```

Or:

```
(async function () {
  await loadScript('/my/script.js');
  // Your async code here
})();
```

Where the definition of `loadScript` is like above

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, I would like to ask a couple of questions. Firstly, if you look at the callback code you provided firstly, in there cb is callback which is executed asynchronously meaning it is run only after script was created Right? Secondly, how cb callback can wait for script to be created and then be executed since JS engine passes document.createElement('script'); into queue and continues executing the rest of the code. Hope you got what I mean

Comment: It doesn't get called after the script is created, but after that the script has been downloaded, which is different. And the JS engine will just register somewhere that a function has to be called once a script is loaded, and it will consider the snippet only when the event is fired. If there is other synchronous code, it will be executed immediately. If there's not any synchronous code, it doesn't matter

Comment: @Christian Traina, you mean, cb callback will be registered somewhere in the memory and will wait until script is loaded Is that correct? By the way, document.createElement('script'); is executed via event loop? since it is asynchronous

Comment: It's oversimplified, but yes, you can think like that. But note: `createElement` is super synchronous. Once you append the created element to the dom, the browser will perform a HTTP request, which is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Because of how the `<script>` tag works. Browsers will load the `<script>` tag synchronously except when:

1. it has an `async` tag set to true
2. it has been created using `document.createElement()`

So the `loadScript` function does the second part.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, look, when JS engine starts executing the code I provided above, it first sees createElement('script') and passes this code into callback queue Right? then continues executing the rest of the code. Then it sees src and document.head and waits until createElement is passed into call stack to be run Right?